# Method for my partial view NewPassword to check if the new password given by the user equals one of the last 10 passwords in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a method of type `ActionResult` called `NewPassword` in my LoginController. My SQL Table is called `Users`. This table holds Id, Username, Password, etc. I want to create a code inside my `NewPassword` that checks if the new password given by the users equals one of the 10 last-entered passwords in the Users table. Passwords are hashed and then stored to the table this is clear. I have created a class with a method called Hash() which converts to Hash Code the passwords. Which would be the best way to do this?

I tried catching the number of rows of the table and after that I used a loop

```
var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == userModel.Username).First();
if (user != null)
{
    if ( /* This new password does not match one of the last 10 chosen passwords */)
    {
        /* Update the password */
    } else 
    {
        /* Show the user an error message */
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to store the used passwords in the `Users` table. Create a separate table to store those. `if (db.PasswordHistory.Where(p => p.Username == userModel.Username).Any(p => newPasswordHash == p.Hash)`?

Comment: "I want to create a code inside my NewPassword that checks if the new password given by the users equals one of the 10 last-entered passwords in the Users table"

Please clarify: Are checking last 10 used passwords by the the same user or what?
Do you have any table that is keeping record of user password histories?

Comment: @codein yes by the same user. He cannot update (change) his password, if the new password is one of the 10 last passwords he has had

Comment: Ok. See the above comment by @itsme86 then

Comment: You should take a look at AspNet Identity to handle your logins/password management.